# illegal_argument_exception while using kafka connector to push to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to push logs from kafka tops to elasticsearch.

My message in kafka:

```
{
  "@timestamp": 1589549688.659166,
  "log": "13:34:48.658 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG health check success",
  "stream": "stdout",
  "time": "2020-05-15T13:34:48.659166158Z",
  "pod_name": "my-pod-789f8c85f4-mt62l",
  "namespace_name": "services",
  "pod_id": "600ca012-91f5-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "host": "ip-192-168-88-59.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
  "container_name": "my-pod",
  "docker_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1435bb2870bfc9d20deb2c483ce07f8e71ec",
  "container_hash": "myregistry",
  "labelpod-template-hash": "9tignfe9r",
  "labelsecurity.istio.io/tlsMode": "istio",
  "labelservice": "my-pod",
  "labelservice.istio.io/canonical-name": "my-pod",
  "labelservice.istio.io/canonical-revision": "latest",
  "labeltype": "my-pod",
  "annotationkubernetes.io/psp": "eks.privileged",
  "annotationsidecar.istio.io/status": "{\"version\":\"58dc8b12bb311f1e2f46fd56abfe876ac96a38d7ac3fc6581af3598ccca7522f\"}"
}
```

This is my connector config:

```
{
  "name": "logs",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "http://es:9200",
    "connection.username": "username",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "tasks.max": "10",
    "topics": "my-pod",
    "name": "logs",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "transforms": "routeTS",
    "transforms.routeTS.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter",
    "transforms.routeTS.topic.format": "${topic}-${timestamp}",
    "transforms.routeTS.timestamp.format": "YYYYMMDD"
  }
}
```

This is the error i'm getting

```
cp-kafka-connect-server [2020-05-15 13:30:59,083] WARN Failed to execute batch 4830 of 18 records with attempt 4/6, will attempt retry after 539 ms. Failure reason: Bulk request failed: [{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [labelservice] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"}
```

I haven't created any mapping beforehand. I'm depending on the connector to create the index.
This is the mapping I have in es which is autocreated.

```
{
  "mapping": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear

> reason":"mapper [labelservice] of different type, current_type [text],
>   merged_type [ObjectMapper]"

It means in your index mapping `labelservice` is defined as `text` but you are sending below data in `labelservice` field:

```
"labelservice": "my-pod",
"labelservice.istio.io/canonical-name": "my-pod",
"labelservice.istio.io/canonical-revision": "latest",
```

This is the format of object type in Elasticsearch, now there is a mismatch in the data-type which caused the error message.

You need to change your mapping and define `labelservice` as object to make it work. Refer [object datatype in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) for more info.